# Issues when trying to sum the content of a list that's in STR type

Tags: python

I've been trying to sum the content of list ['6134,15', '20432,65', '10588795,61'] obtained from a query to a DB2 table using ibm_db module (I'm also using pandas to frame the results). These are dollar amounts, but they are retrieved as strings so I can't sum them. I have tried:

```
# This gets me the list from the column I'm interested in.
amtTot = maind.get('INVOICE_TOTAL') 

for char in amtTot:
    a = char.replace(",",".") 
    b = float(a) 
    print(b)
```

And in return I get each value - that's ok, but I need the sum of them. I tried to apply something like `sum(b)` but I get error "float is not iterable". If I try with `int` instead of `float`, I get "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '6134,15'".

Comment: If you want one liner, `total = sum([float(char.replace(',', '.')) for char in amTot])`should do the job.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, the error means, the function `sum` needs an iterator as parameter. `sum` takes an iterator like list, set or numpy array etc. and returns the sum of the items in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be use a variable to keep track of the sum:

```
total = 0
for char in amtTot:
    a = char.replace(",",".") 
    b = float(a) 
    print(b)
    total += b

print(total)
```

Comment: this totally solved my problem. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cleanList = [float(i.replace(",", ".")) for i in amtTot]
sum(cleanList)
```

Hope this helps!